# Ubuntu 20.04 Raspberry Pi - Can't write anything, every file seems to be in read-only

Tags: server, 20.04, raspberrypi, docker, read-only

I'm currently running **Ubuntu 20.04** (server, not desktop) on my **Raspberry Pi** and I'm noticing that nothing seems to work. I'm able to SSH into my device, and the first problem I see is that the Message of the Day does not appear. Normally, I'll get a message that shows me the temperature of my device, the storage space, load, etc. But now, all I just see when I SSH into my Pi is my last login date and time.

When in my home directory, I try creating a new text file with `sudo nano`. Nano opens up, but at the bottom it says `[Directory '.' is not writable]`.

When I try to do `sudo apt update`, I get the following:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.qi7Ajt - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.VGXMSt - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.GdwBDs - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.zJIneu - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_focal_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_focal-updates_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_focal-backports_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_focal-security_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (30: Read-only file system)
```

This has lead me to believe that my entire system is now read-only. This started happening when I was moving some files on Nextcloud (hosted using Docker) and my device froze. I had no choice but to pull the plug, and now everything is locked. What can I do to fix this? Not sure if this is useful, but I have my Nextcloud files stored on my external HDD, but my Ubuntu is stored on my microSD.

Comment: A RW (read-write) file-system usually flips to RO (read-only) when an issue is detected and requires manual fix (the flipping to RO is to prevent data loss).  Have you looked up your logs, and looked at what the issue is? as usually a suggested solution is given (eg. to manually run `fsck` or perform a *file-system check*)   FYI:  I avoid *pulling the plug* if at all possible, eg. using SysRq keys to safely reboot; however if I did need to, I'd `fsck` the system before I attempted to boot it anyway

Comment: @guiverc How do I look up my logs? And when I ran `sudo fsck -M` (I wanted to excluded my mounted external HDD since there's nothing wrong with it), all I got was `fsck from util-linux 2.34` and nothing happened. Could you also clarify what SysRq keys are? I'm a complete newbie when it comes to Linux systems. This is my first ever Raspberry Pi and I'm just starting to learn.

Comment: SysRq is a key on the keyboard (on some modern keyboards not listed and is achieved via combination of keys), which allow you to bypass any *hanging* user-space program (eg. a GUI) & issue commands directly to the linux kernel. A search with a phone ("magic sysrq" usually shows the wikpedia article which is as good as any) will show commands..  `dmesg` (since last reboot or last system start only) or `journalctl` (includes prior boots) can be used.  You cannot `fsck` whilst a disk is mounted; I usually boot 'live' media though with a 'pi' I'd usually remove card & `fsck` from PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution. It turns out that my microSD card was probably corrupted. I did the following:

1. Install another OS (in my case, Raspbian OS) into a separate USB stick
2. Unplug my corrupted microSD and plug in the USB stick that had Raspbian OS
3. Boot my Raspberry Pi from USB
4. Plug in my corrupted microSD
5. Run `sudo fdisk -l` to find my microSD (in my case, it was `/dev/mmcblk0p1` and `/dev/mmcblk0p2`)
6. Run `sudo fsck -y /dev/mmcblk0p1` and `sudo fsck -y /dev/mmcblk0p2` so it tries to fix whatever corruption was found on my microSD.
7. Plug microSD back in and things should return to normal.